# User defined controller(To be inheritted by all controllers) with instantiated DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have my basic controller with an inherited user defined controller with a call from the Db

```
public class HomeController : MyAppController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string name = Db.Users.First().Name;
        return Content(name);
    }
}
```

Inside the user defined controller we have

```
public class MyAppController : Controller
{
    public FooEntities Db { get; set; }

    public MyAppController() {
        Db = new FooEntities();
    }
}
```

Now I've heard that memory leakage is possible with this method. How can I retain this method and avoid the said disadvantages?

Comment: Where did you hear about these memory leaks? I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: At the very least, you probably ought to override `Dispose` to dispose `Db`.

Comment: There is an override called something like `Dispose` in the controller where you could dispose your context, however I'm not fond of this approach, because for 'reading' it is not really relevant and 'writing' should be limited to a post method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to dispose the context:

```
public class MyAppController : Controller
{
    public FooEntities Db { get; set; }

    public MyAppController() 
    {
        Db = new FooEntities();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    { 
        this.Db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

But if you are doing things properly and working with abstractions (instead of hardcoding specific instances of your DB context into the controller constructor), it's the responsibility of your Dependency Onjection framework to control the lifetime of your context. Ideally they should be per-request. In this case your controller code will look like this:

```
public class MyAppController : Controller
{
    protected IUnitOfWork UoW { get; private set; }

    public MyAppController(IUnitOfWork uow) 
    {
        this.UoW = uow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Before I mark this as answered. Could you please enlighten me with the thing you mentioned about "per-request"?

Comment: It's an object whose lifetime is bound to that of the HTTP request, i.e. it is instantiated at the beginning of the request and disposed at the end.